# Entity Framework 4.1 InverseProperty Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations

Just wanted to know more about `RelatedTo` attribute and I found out it has been replaced by `ForeignKey` and `InverseProperty` attributes in EF 4.1 RC.

Does anyone know any useful resources about the scenarios that this attribute becomes useful?

Should I use this attribute on navigation properties? example:

```
public class Book
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}

  [ForeignKey("FK_AuthorID")]
  public Author Author {get; set;}
}  

public class Author
{
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  // Should I use InverseProperty on the following property?
  public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I add an example for the `InversePropertyAttribute`. It cannot only be used for relationships in self referencing entities (as in the example linked in Ladislav's answer) but also in the "normal" case of relationships between different entities:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("Books")]
    public Author Author {get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("Author")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}
```

This would describe the same relationship as this Fluent Code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
            .HasOptional(b => b.Author)
            .WithMany(a => a.Books);
```

... or ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Books)
            .WithOptional(b => b.Author);
```

Now, adding the `InverseProperty` attribute in the example above is redundant: The mapping conventions would create the same *single relationship* anyway.

But consider this example (of a book library which only contains books written together by two authors):

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    public Author FirstAuthor {get; set;}
    public Author SecondAuthor {get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Book> BooksAsFirstAuthor {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Book> BooksAsSecondAuthor {get; set;}
}
```

The mapping conventions would not detect which ends of these relationships belong together and actually create *four relationships* (with four foreign keys in the Books table). In this situation using the `InverseProperty` would help to define the correct relationships we want in our model:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("BooksAsFirstAuthor")]
    public Author FirstAuthor {get; set;}
    [InverseProperty("BooksAsSecondAuthor")]
    public Author SecondAuthor {get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [InverseProperty("FirstAuthor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> BooksAsFirstAuthor {get; set;}
    [InverseProperty("SecondAuthor")]
    public virtual ICollection<Book> BooksAsSecondAuthor {get; set;}
}
```

Here we would only get *two relationships*. (Note: The `InverseProperty` attribute is only necessary on one end of the relationship, we can omit the attribute on the other end.)

Comment: +1 Good. I hoped you will come and explain it little bit more to get some credits :)

Comment: Lol! But somehow this attribute is in no-mans-land between conventions and Fluent mapping: For simple relationships it's not necessary and for complex relationships everyone will use Fluent code. Probably the reason why it's so uncommon and the only explanation I can think of why even *you* didn't know it :)

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer.

Comment: I've been googling this for a week. You are a god among men.

Comment: A little late but: Should `FirstAuthor` and `SecondAuthor` in `Book` be `virtual` too? In this case I believe you don't need the `Attribute` too.

Comment: expletive word - awesome!! Great tutorial and examples. First rate answer!

Answer (score 28):

`ForeignKey` attribute pairs FK property with navigation property. It can be placed either on FK property or navigation property. It is equivalent of `HasForeignKey` fluent mapping.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Navigation")]
    public virtual int NavigationFK { get; set; }

    public virtual OtherEntity Navigation { get; set; }
}
```

`InverseProperty` is used for defining self referencing relation and pairing navigation properties on both ends. Check [this question for sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691780/navigation-property-without-declaring-foreign-key).

Comment: Ha! it's you again! Thanks EF guru!

Comment: So if I have a master detail scenario (EF4.2), what do I decorate the properties (do I have to)? Say I have a `Master` class with a virtual property `Detail:ICollection<Detail>` and a `Detail` class with a virtual property `Master`.