# Why am I getting an extra foreign key column with Entity Framework Code First Foreign Key Attributes?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I recently came across this strange problem with Entity Framework Code First.

My class looks like this

```
public class Status
{
        [Key]
        public int StatusID { get; set; }     
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MemberID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("MemberID")]
        public virtual Member Member { get; set; }                

        public int PosterID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PosterID")]
        public virtual Member Poster { get; set; }        

        public virtual ICollection<StatusLike> StatusLikes { get; set; }        
        public virtual ICollection<StatusComment> StatusComments { get; set; }
}
```

My Member class looks like this

```
 public class Member
    {
        [Key]
        public int MemberID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MemberCourseTaken> MemberCourseTakens { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Club> FoundedClubs { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        public int AccountSourceID { get; set; }
        public AccountSource AccountSource { get; set; }

        public int AddressID { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }

        public int MemberRankID { get; set; }
        public MemberRank MemberRank { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    }
```

And for whatever reason the database table that is created has the following columns

```
StatusID
Name
MemberID
PosterID
Member_MemberID
```

with `MemberID`, `PosterID`, and `Member_MemberID` being foreign keys.

How can I keep `Member_MemberID` from being generated?

Comment: How many navigation properties from `Member` to `Status` do you have? Show your `Member` class.

Comment: Lots!  I added in the member class to the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `Member_MemberID` column is created because of the `Member.Statuses` property. I can imagine that this is not what you want. Probably members and statuses should exist independent of each other, so you need a junction table.

I don't know if you already use the `OnModelCreating` override of the DbContext, but that's the place to change the mapping between Member and Status:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Entity<Member>().HasMany(m => m.Statuses).WithMany();
}
```

This will create a table MemberStatuses table with the two Id columns as foreign keys. This is a way to model a many-to-many relationship without a navigation property on the "other" side of the association. (I don't think you want a `Members` property in `Status`).

Comment: Some more explanation here would be good.  I really don't understand why a 2-to-many relationship should cause the `Member_MemberID` column to be created.  Why is it needed?

Comment: @Jez You're right, it could be explained a bit better. The `Member_MemberID` field is the FK to status for the one-to-many relationship Member-Statuses. It is created because the association is not seen as the bi-directional part of either `Member` or `Poster`. The point of my solution was that (imo) members and statuses are quite independent entities, not aggregated like order-orderline.

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding what you're saying, @GertArnold.  What is "the association"?  What is "the bi-directional part"?

Comment: "The association" (or relationship) is Member-Statuses. Often associations are bidirectional (Order->Orderlines & Orderline->Order). One FK is enough in that case. But here there are two asssociations Status->Member and one association Member->Statuses. EF is not going to assume which of the two Status->Member associations is bidirectional (or: has the same FK as Member->Statuses) and so creates a third FK. It _is_ possible to tell EF which association is bidirectional, but keeping the the entities independent looked better to me and, apparently, the OP agreed.

Comment: Excellent! The extra explanation made more sense to me. I'm curious... how is it possible to tell EF which association is bidirectional?

Comment: Upon more research I found out that this can be done with the `InverseProperty`. Look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5717272/399435

Answer (score 10):

I've seen this before.  In my case (Using EF 6.1), it was because my Fluent API Mapping was set up like so:

```
// In my EntityTypeConfiguration<Status>
HasRequired(x => x.Member).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberID);
```

That code works perfectly fine, but it doesn't tell EF that my `Member` class's Collection Navigational Property `Status` ha been taken into account.  So, while I explicitly handled the existence of a `Member` Navigational Property in my `Status` Class, I now left an orphaned related collection property.  That orphaned property, being a collection, tells EF that my `Status` class needs to have a Foreign Key to it.  So it creates that on the `Status` Class.

To fix it, I had to be 100% explicit.

```
HasRequired(x => x.Member).WithMany(x => x.Statuses).HasForeignKey(x => x.MemberID)
```

It could bee that your `Statuses` Collection property in `Member` needs an attribute telling it that it is already considered, and not to go auto-creating mappings.  I don't know that attribute.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed it for me!

Comment: omg, thank you. After hours of bashing my head against a wall this fixed it for me. Thanks again!