# EF is creating 2 foreign keys for navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship

The following entity configuration it creating a double foreign key for one of the navigation properties:

```
public User  : IdentityUser
{
     //public string Id { get; set; } //on base class

     public virtual ICollection<Earning> Earnings { get; set; }
}


public class Earning
{

    public int EarningId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
    public string SenderId { get; set; }


}

public class EarningConfiguraiton : EntityTypeConfiguration<Earning>
{
    public EarningConfiguraiton() 
    {
        this.HasRequired(e => e.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Earnings)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

        this.HasRequired(e => e.Sender)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.SenderId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

However it generates 3 foreign keys for 2 navigation properties. "User_Id" is seemingly redundant. Should I remove , if so how?

```
   CreateTable(
            "dbo.Earnings",
            c => new
                {
                    EarningId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserId = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    SenderId = c.String(maxLength: 128),                      
                    User_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.EarningId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.SenderId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.User_Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.SenderId)
            .Index(t => t.User_Id);
```

Further more `context.Users.Include(u => u.Earnings)` only works with `User_Id` column populated, rather than UserId.

I even get this migration generated on a brand new database

Comment: do you add a `EarningConfiguraiton` to the Configuration collection in the `OnModelCreating` of your context ?

Comment: EF automatically registers classes of type EntityTypeConfiguration<> in the assembly so there is no need to add anything. Changes to this  configuration get picked up so I know that's true (how else would it know to generate the SenderId FK above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a long outstanding work item on this issue with the Fluent API not correctly handling inverse navigation properties.  It has been considered to be a low priority issue, and was not included in the 6.1 release due to Triage.  http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1135

Comment: I see, I guess I'm not going crazy. I'm surprised I haven't ran into this before after so long using EF navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm able to get past this but the bounty is still available for a better way.

Gert's comments in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909061/why-am-i-getting-an-extra-foreign-key-column-with-entity-framework-code-first-fo) helped me put it together.

Basically since there are 2 `User` entities on the `Earning`, EF is not going to assume which of them is bi-directional for the `Earnings` collection on the User.

Using `[InversePropoperty]` attribute works but I'm not able to configure this using Fluent Api:

Solution:

```
 public User  : IdentityUser
 {  
     [InverseProperty("User")]
     public virtual ICollection<Earning> Earnings { get; set; }
 }


 public class Earning
 {
     [InverseProperty("Earnings")]
     public virtual User User { get; set; }

     public virtual User Sender { get; set; }
     public string SenderId { get; set; }
  }
```

Now it generates one less foreign key. However I'm unable to configure this using Fluent Api.

```
public class EarningConfiguraiton : EntityTypeConfiguration<Earning>
{
    public EarningConfiguraiton() 
    {
        this.HasRequired(e => e.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.EmailEarnings)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId) //doesnt honor this. creates User_Id anyways
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    }
}
```

I don't know if it's a bug but bounty goes to whoever can figure it out. I'm using EF  6.1.1