# Entity framework trouble

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to setup a one-to-many relationship with entity framework.

I am trying to build a recipe, but a recipe CAN be composed of recipes.

How to achieve that with EF ?

```
public class Recipe
{
    public Recipe()
    {
        Deleted = false;

        Recipes = new List<Recipe>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

I don't need the whole recursive thing(parent, child) only the child I'm interested in. Is it feasible using EF ? Can anyone point me to the right direction

Ex:

Recipe A

Recipe B => A

Recipe C

Recipe D => B

Recipe E => B, C

Comment: Recursive? No. You're thinking of inheritance.

Comment: you don't want or you can't have the parent association because it is much more easy to do with the child and parent association. Are you using data mappings or just leaving the defaults?

Comment: Use two entities. One for Recipe and one for RecipeMap that maps a parent receipt to a child recipe.

Comment: @tnw: yes, all I want is the inheritance

Comment: @GabrielMonteiroNepomuceno: I don't want because I don't need the parent recipe. I use the default mapping, I thought it would have worked, but it is complaining about foreign key constraints, so I believe I need some custom mappings

Comment: @FacioRatio: I thought about that solution, but I thought EF would handle such thing out of the box

Comment: Not sure if the inheritance is the way to go as the object is not a composition of some entites but a composition of the same type of entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a many-to-many relationship, because each recipe can have multiple and multiple parent recipes.  When you create your child recipes, you will have to assign a parent to it, so you must define the parent relationship as well.

You could try the InverseProperty dataannotation, for more info check out this question:
[Entity Framework 4.1 InverseProperty Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716528/entity-framework-4-1-inverseproperty-attribute)