# How i DEFINE 2 foreign keys to the same table to the same list but different entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want that `UserMessage` entity point with `ReciverIdFK` to `SharedManWoman` entity and with `SenderIdFK` to another `SharedManWoman` entity

```
public class SharedManWoman
{
    public List<UserMessage> UserMessages { get; set; }
}

public class UserMessage
{      
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserMessages")]
        public long SenderIdFK { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("UserMessages")]
        public virtual SharedManWoman UserMessages { get; set; } 

        [ForeignKey("UserMessages")]
        public long ReciverIdFK { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("UserMessages")]
        public virtual SharedManWoman UserMessages { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you can't have two properties with the same name.

But, using the following fluent api on at least one of the properties should do the job:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserMessage>()
   .HasOptional(t => t.UserMessages)
   .WithMany()
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to do it with annotations, the following should do the job. Note that your `SharedManWoman` object needs an `Id`. Also, as it stands, the `SharedManWoman`'s pretty much useless since it doesn't have any properties of its own.

```
public class SharedManWoman {
   public long Id { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("Sender")]
   public ICollection<UserMessage> SenderMessages { get; set; }

   [InverseProperty("Receiver")]
   public ICollection<UserMessage> ReceiverMessages { get; set; }
}

public class UserMessage {

   [Key]
   public long Id { get; set; }

   // Note that these are NULLABLE
   public long? SenderIdFK { get; set; }
   public long? ReceiverIdFK { get; set; }


   [ForeignKey("SenderIdFK")]
   public virtual SharedManWoman Sender { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ReceiverIdFK")]
   public virtual SharedManWoman Receiver { get; set; }
}
```

[More Info Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5717272/1254575)

Comment: and how with attribute?

Comment: its possible with one list SenderReciverMessages ?

Comment: No, you can't treat two relationships as one.