# Navigation property without referential integrity constraint in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In EF 6 (code first), is it possible to have a navigation property set-up without enforcing a referential integrity constraint?

For example:

```
public class Person{

    public IList<Pet> Pets { get; set; }

}

public class Pet{

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }

}
```

So in the example above I'd like to be able to add a Pet with an OwnerId, even if that owner does not exist in the Owners table.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5691780/navigation-property-without-declaring-foreign-key

Answer (score 3):

You can define the relationship using the fluent API.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Pet>
    .hasOptional(p => p.Owner)
    .willCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This will configure the relational property as optional, and will ensure that cascade delete does not take effect.  You can create a `Pet` without an `Owner`, and deleting an `Owner` will not delete the associated `Pets`.

**However** you cannot assign `Pet.OwnerId` to an `OwnerId` that doesn't exist in the `Owner` table.  If you truly need to have some way of tracking invalid `OwnerId` values, you either need to have a separate property which you manually update with an arbitrary value, or you would need to define these objects without using a navigation property, and perform your lookups manually.

It would be an exceptional situation where you would need to supply an arbitrary value for `OwnerId` that doesn't match the `Owner` table;  In 99% of all cases, an optional relationship which accepts a valid `OwnerId` or `null` is all that is necessary.

The `OwnerId` property isn't actually necessary on the `Pet` object, but if it is present, it should be set to `int?` to be nullable.

Comment: and `OwnerID` should be of type `int?`.

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer**: Don't use EF. The whole point of Object **Relational** Mappers is to ensure you have valid data as well as help with retrieving/persisting it

All you really want is some sort of mapper.

**Long Answer**: Curious myself